# Find the length of a vector based on a rule

Tags: java, math, vector, trigonometry

I am creating vertex array for a mesh with given points.So far I was able to create a continuous mesh with thickness.However there is a problem at the intersection of two line segments, the vectors between those segment's sizes needs to be bigger or smaller depending on the situation in order to have a continuous look.

**What I have now:**

[image: What I have now]

---

With the given angles theta1 and theta2, how can I calculate the length of red vectors?

**What I want:**
[image: What I want]

---

**How I structured my mesh:** 
[image: How I structured my mesh]

Comment: This seems like a maths question, not a programming question.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I now posted it on math stackexchange, but I think people can still provide me with some algorithms or suggestions on the right path on SO as well.I am trying to solve this for more than a week and I am totally lost right now.

Comment: What's the problem with what you have now? What would you like to have in the end? It seems to me that you have not fully answered these questions yet.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably making it more complicated than it needs to be.

Let's start by calculating the red arrows. For any line segment `(p_i, p_j)`, we can calculate the segment's normal with:

```
dir = normalize(p_j - p_i)
normal = (-dir.y, dir.x)  //negate if you want the other direction
```

At the connection point between two segments, we can just average (and re-normalize) the incident normals. This gives us the red arrows.

The only question that remains is how much you need to shift. The resulting offset for the line segment `o_l` given an offset of the vertex `o_v` is:

```
o_l = o_v * dot(normal_l, normal_v)
```

This means the following: Both normals are unit vectors. Hence, their dot product is at most one. This is the case when both line segments are parallel. Then, the entire offset of the vertex is transferred to the line. The smaller the angle becomes, the smaller becomes the transferred offset. E.g. if the angle between two consecutive line segments is 120°, then the dot product of normals is 0.5. If you shift the vertex by 1 unit along its normal, both line segment will have a thickness of 0.5.

So, in order to produce a specific line thickness (`o_l`), we need to shift the vertex by `o_v`:

```
o_v = o_l / dot(normal_l, normal_v)
```

The construction with averaging the line segments' normal for the vertex normal ensures that `dot(normal_l1, normal_ v) = dot(normal_l2, normal_v)`, i.e. the resulting line thickness is equal for both lines in any case.